# Convert polygon co-ordinates to GeoJSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geojson, polygon-creation

I need to convert the below polygon to a GeoJSON object,

"Polygon":"146.90805846452713 -42.942663073539734, 147.01517516374588 -42.87627762556076, 147.15525084733963 -42.745309352874756, 147.03989440202713 -42.5898035466671, 147.08933287858963 -42.466334521770477, 147.16623717546463 -42.289817214012146, 147.15799742937088 -42.2268003821373, 147.22940856218338 -42.212562054395676, 147.26718145608902 -42.091744154691696, 147.20950323343277 -41.977504372596741, 147.03646856546402 -42.095820367336273, 146.85519415140152 -41.95095506310463, 146.88540655374527 -41.8241830766201"

Expected output:
"geoPolygon":
{
"type":"Polygon",
"coordinates":[[
[146.90805846452713,-42.942663073539734],
[147.01517516374588 ,-42.87627762556076]......
]]
}

Comment: Is the polygon  in JSON format now or txt?

Comment: hi all, just found a fix for the above question, made use of wkx javascript library to convert into valid geoJSON coordinates. link for wkx - https://rodic.fr/blog/online-conversion-between-geometric-formats/